# Guessing a number

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to create a program that gives you three tries to find any given number. It's going to essentially be a guessing game. The problem is, I have to do this without any loops. So far, I'm only able to get input from the user, read that input and tell them if they've won or 'lost' the game. The program only runs once and stops(as expected).

I was told that it could be done without loops, albeit with a lot more code. Can you guys let me know what I'm doing wrong here and give me some pointers on what I should change? If you need clarification let me know.
Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ran = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int x = ran.nextInt();

        if (x < 3) {
            System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");

            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        } else if (x > 3) {
            System.out.println("Too high. Try again");

        } else if(x == 3) {
            System.out.println("You win. Nice job.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You lose");
        }

        System.out.println("Number Guessing Game (c) 2017 Anna Gibson");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use recursion or just put your guessing code in its own​ (static) method and call that three times in a row. Though I really doubt that "not using loops" is going to be an in any way helpful undertaking...

Comment: How is the number that the user guesses chosen?

Comment: I was going to set the number myself, hence x==3, but I had a feeling I was going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using recursion. See this program. Find explanations within comments.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

    private static Scanner ran = new Scanner(System.in);

    //this is number of tries you want to give to user
    private static int counter = 5;

    //The actual number
    private static final int NUM = 3;

    public static boolean guessingMachine() {
        //counter indicates that number of attempts remaining
        if(counter == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        counter--;

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int x = ran.nextInt();

        if (x < NUM) {
            System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
            //try again... call this method again
            return guessingMachine();
        } else if (x > NUM) {
            System.out.println("Too high. Try again");
            //try again... call this method again
            return guessingMachine();
        } else {
            //x == NUM success
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result = guessingMachine();

        if(result) 
            System.out.println("You win. Nice job.");
        else 
            System.out.println("You lose");

        System.out.println("Number Guessing Game (c) 2017 Anna Gibson");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could next conditions:

```
get user input
if input is correct, congratulation user and exit
    else
        get user input //second attempt
        if input is correct, congratulation user and exit
...
```

You can continue from there. The code you provided, where you tell the user if they are too high or low, would have to be included in each of the branches of the pseudocode above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main purpose of this exercise is intended for you to strengthen your nested if-else concepts.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class HelloWorld{

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int num=3;
    int count=1;
    Scanner ran = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int x = ran.nextInt();

    if(x>num || x<num)
    {
        System.out.println("incorrect guess");
        count++;
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
         x = ran.nextInt();
         if(x>num || x<num)
         {
              System.out.println("incorrect guess");
              count++;
                          System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                           x = ran.nextInt();
                           if(x>num || x<num)
                           {
                               System.out.println("incorrect guess YOU LOSE");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                                               System.out.println("YOU WIN");
                           }
         }
         else
         {
               System.out.println("YOU WIN");
         }

    }

    if(x==num && count==1)
    {
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
    }

    System.out.println("Number Guessing Game (c) 2017 Anna Gibson");
 }
}
```